# Display login page and return back to previous route/page with Flowrouter

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, flow-router, atmosphere.js

I want to build a scenario where if a user wants to access a secure page and they are not logged in they get redirected to a login page like so.

```
FlowRouter.route('/add',{
    name: 'add',
    triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
        if(!Meteor.userId()){
            redirect('login/add');
        }
    }],
    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('noHeroLayout', {
            main: 'add'
        });
    }
});
```

Basically the secure page 'add' checks if the user is logged in, if not redirect to login/add. Once the login route is called it checks if a route to link back was provided like so:

```
FlowRouter.route('/login/:callback',{
    name: 'login',
    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('noHeroLayout', {
            main: 'login'
        });
    }
});
FlowRouter.route('/login',{
    name: 'login',
    action(){
        BlazeLayout.render('noHeroLayout', {
            main: 'login'
        });
    }
});
```

Now for my login.js logic it looks like this

```
'submit #app-login-user-internal': function(e,t){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = t.find('#app-email-login-internal').value;
    var password = t.find('#app-password-login-internal').value;
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password,function(err){
        if(err){
            alert("Wrong Credentials");
        }
        else{
            var callback = FlowRouter.getParam('callback');
            if(!callback){
                FlowRouter.go('home');
            }
            else{
                FlowRouter.go(callback);
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Basically on submit if a callback exist in the login route redirect to that callback route if the user has logged in, if no callback was provided go home.

My issue is when no callback is provided I get redirected to home with no issues. It's when I call 'add' when I am not logged in, I get the following error on the console.

`There is no route for the path: login/add`

Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Change your redirect to this

```
redirect('/login/add');
```

Add a slash.